# User input range set color, value, Bold: Run Time Error '1004': Application Defined - Object Defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to Set the Value, Bold, and Color of a user input range

```
Sub Q3()
  Dim Rng As Range
  Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
  Set ActiveSheet.Range(Rng).Select.Value = "test"
  Range(Rng).Select.Bold = True
  Range(Rng).Select.Font.Color = -16776961
End Sub
```

Error 1004 Application Defined - Object Defined Error
Another attempted code:

```
Sub Q3()
  Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
    Set ActiveSheet.Range(Rng).Select.Value = "test"
    Range(Rng).Select.Bold = True
    Range(Rng).Select.Font.Color = -16776961
End Sub
```

Error 1004 Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is off. `Rng` is already a range so no need to wrap it in 'Range' (or Select).

You might want to first check something is returned by the inputbox.

```
Sub Q3()

  Dim Rng As Range

  Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
  With Rng
    .Value = "test"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = -16776961
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I can now run the code with no errors from VBA. When attempting to add a button to the worksheet Msg Box displays "Reference Must be to a Macro Sheet"

Comment: Probably because Q3 is a cell reference so change the name of your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @SJR you need to use error handling to catch the case if the user presses the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button. Otherwise you will run into an error because the `InputBox` returns a boolean `False` which cannot be `Set` to an object variable.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcedureQ3()
   Dim Rng As Range
   On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if user presses cancel
   Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
   On Error Goto 0 're-activate error reporting

   If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'exit if user pressed cancel

   With Rng
       .Value = "test"
       .Font.Bold = True
       .Font.Color = -16776961
   End With
End Sub
```